# "int" to "generic" data type gives errors in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, generic-programming

I am c# beginner and created `huffman tree` which works for "int" type symbol but next step is to make it `generic`.In explain this `symbol`should work for every `data type`.**By every data type i mean symbol could be of type int, ulong,short etc. Actually i am reading a `binary file` and trying to find the frequency of each symbol repeating (number of times the symbol repeats is it's frequency), so this symbol in my node should work for "short", "long", "unsigned" on 32/64 bit architecture. Currently i have used "int" in my code but it may be "short" or any other.**

I have tried so but i have errors, My code is given below and it contains the line number that has errors. And the errors are :
And the errors obtained are :

```
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$ gmcs z.cs 
z.cs(13,23): warning CS0693: Type parameter `K' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman<K>'
z.cs(10,18): (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
z.cs(37,43): error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `K' and `int'
z.cs(50,41): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `K'
z.cs(283,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `K' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(285,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(286,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(288,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
Compilation failed: 6 error(s), 1 warnings
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$
```

And the code is :

```
        namespace final_version_Csharp
         {
    Line 10: public class Huffman<K> where K :  IComparable<K>
            {
                public int data_size, length, i, is_there;
    Line 13:        public class Node<K> 
                {
                    public Node<K> next, left, right;
                    public K symbol;
                    public int freq;
                    public int is_processed;
                }
                public Node<K> front, rear;
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                public Huffman(string[] args) 
                {
                    front = null;
                    rear = null;
                    using(var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0]))) 
                    {
                        while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
                        {
Line 37:                        int processingValue = stream.ReadByte(); 
                            {
                                Node<K> pt, temp;
                                bool is_there = false;
                                pt = front;
                                while (pt != null) 
                                {
                                    if (pt.symbol == processingValue) 
                                    {
                                        pt.freq++;
                                        is_there = true;

                                        break;
                                    }
                                    temp = pt;
                                    pt = pt.next;
                                }
                                if (is_there == false) 
                                {
                                    temp = new Node<K>();
Line 50:                            temp.symbol = processingValue;
                                    temp.freq = 1;
                                    temp.left = null;
                                    temp.right = null;
                                    temp.next = null;
                                    temp.is_processed = 0;
                                    if (front == null) 
                                    {
                                        front = temp;
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        temp.next = front;
                                        front = temp;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stream.Close();
                        //////////////////////////////
                    }
                }

        ..................................
               public class MyClass 
            {
                public static void Main(string[] args) 
                {
    Line 283:       Huffman<K>  ObjSym = new Huffman<K>(args); //object creation
                    Console.WriteLine("\nReading the Binary file......");
    Line 285:       ObjSym.Print_tree(ObjSym.front);
    Line 286:       ObjSym.huffman_node_processing();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThe encoding of symbols are :");
    Line 288:       ObjSym.GenerateCode(ObjSym.rear, "");

                }
            }
        }
```

Could some one please help me in removing these errors and make this "symbol" work for all data types like "short","long" etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems, here.

- There is no type `Node` in your program; references to `Node` need to be to `Node<K>` instead.
- Once the previous item is resolved, you will discover that you assumed in several places that you will always have a `Node<int>`, which need not be the case.  You'll need to figure out how to put the output of `ReadByte()` into a `K` and how to compare it to `pt.symbol`.
- The compiler doesn't want the same placeholder type in nested class definitions.  Instead of `class Node<K>`, try `class Node<T> where T : K`.
- The first line of `Main()` can't use the placeholder type.  It needs to be the type of data that the tree will store.

Comment: Bit explain please ? I have several Node type in program . I all definition i have Node. Could you please explain bit more if i am wrong ?

Comment: You're close.  `Node` would be a fixed type.  `Node<K>` is generic.  They're not interchangeable or related, just like you can't just use `List` and `List<>` together.  If you change all your `Node`s to `Node<K>`s, you'll see.

Comment: I have resolved the first point but second problem i am still not able to understand. I am getting error in the line where i have function definition containing "ref" (I HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION FOR THIS), The error is z.cs(83,16): error CS0305: Using the generic type `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman<K>.Node<K>' requires `1' type argument(s)

Comment: Almost there.  The second item I listed should take care of lines #37 and 50---how you fix them depends on the logic you need.  The last four errors are because `K` is a placeholder name, so you can't create a tree of them; change that to `int` or `string` or whatnot.  That first, though, is tedious.  I'm adding an item to my list.

Comment: John thanks, Ok i am trying , I will let you know if it works.

Comment: z.cs(20,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
 There are 3 similar errors at line 72,83 and 267.

Comment: What does the code look like now?  My copy at least compiles, though I'm pretty sure it won't run.  Did you just change the first line of the `Node<K>` class declaration?  I think the rest of it is fine.

Comment: errors are all inside static void Main(string[] args) function: error CS0246: The type or namespace name `K' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
z.cs(288,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(289,13): error CS0841: A local variable `ObjSym' cannot be used before it is declared
z.cs(291,13): error CS0841: A local vari

Comment: Oh, very good!  Double-check the last item on my list, then:  There is no _real_ type `K`, so you can't have an object in your main program of type `Huffman<K>`.  Whatever you're planning to analyze for compression (`int`, `string`, `List<Stack<Application>>`, etc.), you'll need to change line #288 to match it.